# Displacement of a body in free fall

Tags: kinematics

Suppose a ball is thrown up from the ground with some velocity. Let vertically up be the positive direction and vertically down be the negative direction and let the thrower be at the origin. What will be the sign of displacement after it has reached it's maximum height and is still descending?

I think it will be negative since it's displacement will be in the negative direction, although it's position will always be positive. Am I correct?

Comment: Doesn't that depend on where you put the origin? Maybe I don't understand what your definition of "displacement" is.

Comment: @Floris The thrower is standing on the origin.

Comment: Its displacement will be zero, if you catch the ball again at the origin.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your definition of "displacement" and "position" for me? The velocity (with is rate of displacement, I suppose) will be negative after it has peaked, but since you are always above the origin, your position is always >=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displacement is a vector quantity.

In "our world", it usually has three components (x,y and z) and a length. Of course, the length of a vector is always positive. So how could displacement be negative? If you mean "the Z component of displacement", then by your own definition Z is positive above the origin.

The only thing that goes negative is the velocity after the maximum height has been reached, or $dZ/dt$ for $t>v_{init}/g$

When the ball has returned back to the thrower, the displacement is once again zero.

Comment: The motion in our example is one-dimensional motion.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer - except that Z is the only dimension. Since the other two (X and Y) are assumed to be zero, this just means that the length of the vector is equal to the absolute value of Z (as I said, length is always a positive quantity).

Comment: This is what I thought: As the ball is coming back to us but is still above the ground, it's position at a time instant will always be less than it's position at the previous time instant. Since displacement is change in position, the change in position will be negative. Am i correct?

Comment: You need to make a distinction between "instantaneous change in position" (=velocity, negative when ball is returning back to earth) and "change in position since the start" (current position of ball, positive until caught again). I think that's why you are struggling with this concept.

Comment: So if we were to plot the motion of the ball, the displacement-time graph would never be below the time axis? BTW, which of the quoted phrases is the correct definition of displacement?

Comment: I believe that the displacement-time graph would look like an inverted parabola that is always above zero, and that the second phrase is the correct one (displacement refers to a specific reference point; in this case "the position of the ball at $t=0$ makes sense).

Comment: Then what is the difference between displacement and position?

Comment: When you choose the starting point as your origin, and you work in one dimension, they are the same thing - I think. See the link in dolphus333's answer.

Comment: What is the difference between the two in two dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

The sign of the displacement will be positive.  When the ball reaches the ground again the displacement will be back to zero.  The ball was thrown vertically, so there's no horizontal displacement to worry about.  See http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-1/Distance-and-Displacement for a definition of displacement.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113942/throwing-an-object-in-the-air) where there is the formula for an object thrown up; the formula is: 
$$S=\frac{v_0^2}{2g}\tag{1}$$
The formula for the space is $S=\frac12at^2$ and substituting $t$ $\left(t=\frac{v_0}{g}\right)$ we have:
$$S_{tot}=\frac{v_0^2}{2g}+\frac12g\frac{v_0^2}{g^2}=\frac{v_0^2}{g}$$

Comment: Isn't that the formula for position?

Comment: I don't know but at school I studied that exists a formula easier to use that is: $$\Delta x=\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}$$ which is related the formula I used.